# Source code for javax jws package

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I installed Jave SE and I was able to import javax.jws.WebMethod in Eclipse. But the src.zip that comes with Java SE doesn't seem to have the source code for javax.jws package. Where can I download the source code?

Comment: The source code is available here: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.0-b02/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [site](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/jws/WebMethod.java?av=f) from OpenJDK, at the left menu, click on the 'Files', you can check other source files under the package javax.jws

Comment: I am just looking for a jar file that I can add to eclipse and view the code. Wondering why the source code is not part of the src.zip provided in JDK installation

Comment: Beats me too. But my guess would probably be due to the copyright or there might be political issue between oracle and others. *shrug*, not sure really, you will have to check with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Repackaged sources are available from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/javaee-api/javax.jws/3.1.2.2/ for instance.